# Python3.5.2, selenium 3.0.0b2, Firefox 48.0: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, firefox

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/****/PycharmProjects/********/load_all_params.py", line     2, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-    packages\selenium-3.0.0b2-py3.5.egg\selenium\webdriver\__init__.py", line 25, in     <module>
    from .safari.webdriver import WebDriver as Safari  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-    packages\selenium-3.0.0b2-py3.5.egg\selenium\webdriver\safari\webdriver.py",     line 49
    executable_path = os.environ.get("SELENIUM_SERVER_JAR")
                                                      ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My question is this an error with my code or is this error caused by update to selenium-3.0.0b2? The weird thing is that I am using Firefox(48.0) and here the Safari is listed. What is going on?!

The script I wrote has no spaces or tabs - its just a list of commands.
My code sample:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://192.168.99.100:8080/***/***")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
element = driver.find_element_by_id("lv-username")
```

and so on...

Comment: Where is this line `executable_path = os.environ.get("SELENIUM_SERVER_JAR")`?? and what it does??

Comment: "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-    packages\ . It also looks suspicious that there are spaces between site- and packages. Although it is reading files and stacktrace also points to SELENIUM_SERVER_JAR, so the value is SELENIUM_SERVER_JAR environment variable looks more suspicious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error and what worked for me was going to the path of the **init**.py in your case it would be

"C:\Users*****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-    packages\selenium-3.0.0b2-py3.5.egg\selenium\webdriver__init__.py"

Then just comment out the line

from .safari.webdriver import WebDriver as Safari  # noqa

That is the one for the safari browser. Since that is not the one you want to use anyways.

Answer (score 2):

I've got an even better solution, because the fix is rather simple:

Go to `..\selenium\webdriver\safari\webdriver.py`

And indent the mentioned line into the if clause.

Result should look like:

```
if not executable_path is None:
  executable_path = os.environ.get("SELENIUM_SERVER_JAR")
self.service = Service(executable_path, port=port, quiet=quiet, use_legacy=use_legacy_driver)
self.service.start()
```

After that it imports just fine!

Comment: The other step (for me at least) was to convert tabs to spaces. So at first I was getting the same error as the original post. The 2nd line in your example (executable_path = os...) contained 1 tab and then 4 spaces. Following suit of the rest of the module, I converted the 1 tab into 4 spaces. Trying to import at that point gave me a new error "IndentationError: expected an indented block". As you pointed out, that line needs further indentation, so I added 4 more spaces. Voila!

tl;dr – Line 49 of ..\safari\webdriver.py was indented with 1 tab and 4 spaces. Replace the 1 tab with 8 spaces.

Comment: @kayge I also filed this issue on their Github site, because they already had fixed it in another issue but simply forgot to update the archive on the pypi site. The update will be included in the next beta release, "whenever that will be"

Answer (score 0):

As Meerlin mentioned , indent that line the webdriver.py, but you cant indent just one line because there are 3 lines under that if loop - if you edit just one line you are changing the logic of webdriver.py and pushing the remaining 2 lines out of the if loop. So the result should look like:

```
if not executable_path is None:
        executable_path = os.environ.get("SELENIUM_SERVER_JAR")
        self.service = Service(executable_path, port=port, quiet=quiet, use_legacy=use_legacy_driver)
        self.service.start()
```

Comment: Actually the other statements are not related to the `if` statement and therefore do not need to be indented, because this will only fix the `executable_path` variable if it has no value assigned.